# How can the *shell command output* buffer be kept in the background?

Tags: emacs

How can I tell emacs not to pop up the `*Shell Command Output*` buffer when calling a shell command like this?

```lisp
(shell-command MY_COMMAND)
```

Currently emacs splits the current window into two, showing the (mostly irrelevant) output buffer.  To me it would be completely sufficient if I could look it up later if I feel like it.

Comment: `shell-command` is a fancy function that uses `start-process` -- the latter offers more control -- here is an excerpt from the doc string of `shell-command`:   `In Elisp, you will often be better served by calling 'call-process' or 'start-process' directly, since it offers more control and does not impose the use of a shell (with its need to quote arguments).`  By using start process, you can also set the output buffer to `nil`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe using `shell-command` was the root of the problem. I think I found a solution with `call-process` which works, although there may be a more elegant way:

```
(call-process-shell-command
 "cat ~/.emacs.d/init.el"
 nil "*Shell Command Output*" t
 )
```

Answer (score 9):

`shell-command` takes an optional argument `OUTPUT-BUFFER` where you can specify the buffer to output to. If it is `t` (actually not a buffer-name and not `nil`) it will be output in the current buffer. So we wrap this into a `with-temp-buffer` and will never have to bother with it:

```lisp
(with-temp-buffer
  (shell-command "cat ~/.emacs.d/init.el" t))
```

Comment: Yes, but this still pops up the `*Messages*` buffer.

Comment: @quazgar Oh, it didn't do that for small outputs in my tests. I'll try to hack around.

Comment: Yes, while a simple temp-buffer does not show any output at all, I think this qualifies as "trouble solved".

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, if **the shell command itself** produces no output, then the emacs `*Shell Command Output*` buffer won't pop open.

Therefore, to avoid the output buffer, silence the output of the command.

One easy way is:

- add `" > /dev/null 2>&1"` to the end of any shell command.

(Caveat: I'm unsure if `/dev/null` exists on 100% of platforms where one can run emacs, but on every Linux distro it should be fine.)

If the call to elisp function `shell-command` is in an elisp script, then you could change this:

```
(shell-command cmd)
```

to this:

```
(shell-command (concat cmd " > /dev/null 2>&1"))
```

If you occasionally do want to monitor the output, then you could create one wrapper function that suppresses the output via `/dev/null`, and one wrapper function with no suppression, and toggle between them as you wish.

The above advice was tested on: *GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2017-09-20 on lcy01-07, modified by Debian*

Answer (score 1):

This utility function might help. It returns the actual value of the shell command

```lisp
(defun shell-command-as-string (cmd)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max)
                             cmd t)
    (buffer-string)))
```

Answer (score 0):

What's even better, is to use

```
(shell-command (concat cmd " 1>&2") t t)
```

This way, the output is saved in the error buffer, should you want to look at it. But it does not pop up automatically.